# Extremely simple Node.js API call returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have been going through tutorials and browsing pages, but still don't understand what is missing/wrong (I know, I fail even the ultimate beginner level..)

My aim is to get the value of property 'market_ask', but I receive result 'Undefined'.
Would any of you be able to give me some pointers?
The API documentation is at https://developers.quoine.com/#get-products

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.quoine.com", false);
xhr.send("GET", '/products/1' );

console.log(xhr.responseXML.market_ask);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLHTTPRequest are asynchronous, i.e. when the code reaches `console.log()`the response hasn't arrived yet.

The following should work:

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// completion callback
xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(data.market_ask);
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.quoine.com/products/1");
xhr.send();
```

**EDIT** With the above I get the following output:

```
$ node xmlhttprequest.js 
{ UNSENT: 0,
  OPENED: 1,
...
  responseText: '{"id":"1",...}',
  responseXML: '',
...
  dispatchEvent: [Function] }
{"id":"1",...,"market_ask":10084.236,...}
10084.236
```

If you can use jQuery, i.e. your script will run in a Browser, then I would suggest to use `ajax()` with promises instead, e.g.

```
$.ajax('https://api.quoine.com/products/1')
 .then(() => {
     // success ...
 })
 .catch(error => {
     // failure ...
 });
```

**EDIT2** This is how you would wrap the first variant using Promisesin Node.js, f.ex. as a utility function:

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
            try {
                if (xhr.status !== 200)
                    throw new Error(`request failed with ${xhr.status}`);
                const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                resolve(response);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
        xhr.addEventListener("error", reject);
        xhr.open("GET", "https://api.quoine.com/products/1");
        xhr.send();
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log("Market ask", response.market_ask);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Stefan, thank you very much for your prompt and helpful response!  
This indeed returned a result. The market_ask is coming back as part of the responseText though.  
Would you know how I can assign specifically the market_ask value to a variable?  
I tried the below, but that results in error 'Unexpected end of JSON input'  

  
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(jsonResponse["market_ask"]);
  
p.s. I'll be looking into your suggestion regarding jQuery and ajax() as well.

Comment: Hmm, your approach looks correct. 

I've now had time to test my suggestion and updated my answer with the output. The above code works and I can parse the JSON response and extract `market_value`.

Comment: BTW: if your code is supposed to run only in Node.js, then you won't be able to use jQuery. It only works in the Browser.